# How to embed a file into spring boot native image?

Tags: java, spring-boot, graalvm, graalvm-native-image, paketo

I want to put a file inside an image generated by spring boot native image. But as far as I tried to search, there's no such option (or I couldn't find it) in neither spring boot maven plugin, paketo buildpack nor graalvm itself. I found that you can put resources in using `-H:IncludeResources`, however I need an actual file inside image's filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have files as resources, read them using `Class::getResource`, and embed them into the image using `-H:IncludeResources`.

Remember native images are not Docker images, they don't have "filesystem" inside. They are just regular executables.

Comment: Not sure its a good idea, but you could embed the contents of what you want as a multi-line string. You could also set an argument or system property to point your application to a directory where it can find the resources it requires. You just need to ship those with the binary, which is where a container image comes in handy.

Comment: "> Remember native images are not Docker images, they don't have "filesystem" inside. They are just regular executables."


I think that's my problem. When looking inside generated image, I noticed there's only one executable and nothing else, so maybe it is indeed not possible (I though it is because of mentions of /workspace being default directory and implications of it).